# Convert exponential notation to decimal number in awk

Tags: awk, floating-point

I have space-separated file. This file contains text as well as numbers in exponential format. I want to convert exponential numbers to actual decimal values. Can someone suggest how I can achieve this?

Comment: if the file contains text that should not be converted, then we'd need to see sample input so that it's clearer how to pick out the values that *do* need to be converted.

Comment: did you mean you have numbers in scientific notation and want them truned into decimal.. for example 1.2e-3 into 0.0012 ??

Comment: Yes. Want to convert exponential number to decimal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With GNU `awk`:

```
gawk -v RS='[-+]?[0-9.]+[eE][-+]?[0-9]+' \
     -v ORS= \
     -v CONVFMT=%.1000g '{print $0 (RT == "" ? "" : +RT)}'
```

`gawk` stores what is matched by the record separator into the `RT` variable which we convert to floating point without exponent with the `CONVFMT`.

For higher precision, for instance for `1e123` to be turned into `1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` instead of `999999999999999977709969731404129670057984297594921577392083322662491290889839886077866558841507631684757522070951350501376`, with gawk 4.1 or above add `-M -v PREC=1000` (1000 being the number of *bits*)

Comment: All these command need to be run at once ? I m trying to run them in VIM.

Comment: It's all one command, and yes, you have to run the whole thing. You should probably put it into a script.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
echo "3.85196e+06" | perl -ne 'printf "%d\n", $_;'
```

Comment: While this demonstrate a specific conversion, you might answer the more general question of "converting (any) exponential numbers to decimal".

Comment: this command works fine with positive exponential numbers, but its not working with negative exponentials. Can you explain how your command works. I dont know perl. Thanks